# Not getting desired result when using Hibernate to get count of elements between two particular dates

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

This is the code that is written to evaluate the desired result:

```
   Calendar c7DaysAgo = Calendar.getInstance(); // 7 days ago
    c7DaysAgo.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);

    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance(); // today
    today.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Checkin.class)
            .add(Restrictions.like("fbuid", id))
            .add(Restrictions.between("date", today.getTime(), c7DaysAgo.getTime()));
    List<Checkin> checkinList = criteria.list();
    return checkinList.size();
```

The table values that is being hit to retrieve the values is:

| id | date               |fbuid | number |

|  1 |2012-12-04 18:41:34 | 1111 |     16 |

|  2 |2012-12-04 18:41:34 | 1111 |      2 |

I need the count of rows that fall between today and 7 days before.
But I am getting a value 0 instead of 2.

please help me as i cannot figure out what is going wrong!

Comment: How is your `date` defined? As `long` or as `java.util.Date`? If latter is the case, you need to pass `Date` instances to ranges but not `long`s.

Comment: I have defined in my model as follows:

 private Date date = new Date();

And my table schema(for the date column) is :

date         | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |

Comment: OK, this looks good then. Another question - why do you use `Restrictions.like` for identifier? Should it not be `Restrictions.eq`?

Comment: But I do not think that is going wrong/not working correctly because if I use only .add(Restrictions.like(blah,blah)) it works fine for the desired result ...the date is not getting evaluated properly...

Comment: The best you can do now is to enable TRACE logging for `org.hibernate.SQL` and see how your query translates. This might give some hints.

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs.  This is what i get when i print the criteria:  CriteriaImpl(birdsquare.model.Checkin:this[][fbuid like 1275585577, date between Sat Dec 08 17:52:37 GMT+05:30 2012 and Sat Dec 01 17:52:37 GMT+05:30 2012])   I did set the TRACE logging like that :        ourSessionFactory = new Configuration().setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true").configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
but i did not know where to check...could you please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my mistake....the parameters for between were in the wrong order...it should be

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Checkin.class)
            .add(Restrictions.like("fbuid", id))
            .add(Restrictions.between("date", c7DaysAgo.getTime(),today.getTime()));
```